# Build FFmpeg with ".EXE" files of external libraries?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, software, windows

this is my first question on StackExchange!

I recently got into building FFmpeg on Windows and build successfully the vanilla and the external library versions of this program!

I noticed that it only takes in the "include" and "lib" inputs from the source to link the external libraries to FFmpeg. (--extra-cflags && --extra-ldflags)

I also saw an option to specify the location of .exe files of the external libraries(--extra-ldexeflags)!

So, I was wondering if I could compile FFmpeg with external library support just by specifying the path to the .exe files of the external libraries using --extra-ldexeflags.

It would be great if I receive an answer to this humble question of mine!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Although this question *is* video-related, I feel like you might get better answers on superuser.stackexchange.com